# Unknown host in Java RMI

Tags: java, rmi

I'm working on a Java RMI distribuited system and I have 2 VMs running ubuntu on my local machine (ubuntu- (master) IP = 192.168.101.131 and ubuntu- (slave) IP = 92.168.101.137). Can I run my bankServer.jar on both VMs (within a tomcat). The ubuntu- (master) database automatically replicates on ubuntu- (slave). So far so good. Server mentions (in portuguese) that is running in the default port 1099.

```
Cubuntu@ubuntu:/var/www/html/classes$ java -cp ./code/:jar/serverBanco.jar -
Dja.rmi.server.codebase=file:jar/computeInterfaces.jar -
Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.101.131 -
Djava.security.policy=file:jar/all.policy bank.BankServer
Default RMI Port = 1099
Servidor iniciado...
```

Now when running the client on my local machine my program first ping the host to see if he is online and, if ok, binds to it the registry like so:

```
InetAddress inet = null;
     InetAddress inet2 = null;
     String rmi_adress;
        //ping 
        inet = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { (byte) 192, (byte) 168, 101, (byte) 137 });
        System.out.println("Enviando Ping Request para host: " + inet);
        System.out.println(inet.isReachable(5000) ? "Resposta: Host online" : "Resposta: Host offline");

        inet2 = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] { (byte) 192, (byte) 168, 101, (byte) 131 });
        System.out.println("Enviando Ping Request para host: " + inet2);
        System.out.println(inet2.isReachable(5000) ? "Resposta: Host online" : "Resposta: Host offline");

        try {
            registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("rmi://127.0.0.1/BankServer");
            if (inet.isReachable(5000)) {
                rmi_adress = "rmi://192.168.101.137/BankServer";
                registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(rmi_adress);      
                System.out.println("RMI Port set to " + rmi_adress);
                bank = (OperationsInterface) registry.lookup(rmi_adress);
            }else {
                rmi_adress =  "rmi://192.168.101.131/BankServer";
                registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(rmi_adress);      
                System.out.println("RMI Port set to " + rmi_adress);
                bank = (OperationsInterface) registry.lookup(rmi_adress);
            }
```

But when running the client it can not recognize the host. This is the exception I'm getting:

```
Enviando Ping Request para host: /192.168.101.137
Resposta: Host online
Enviando Ping Request para host: /192.168.101.131
Resposta: Host online
RMI Port set to rmi://192.168.101.137/BankServer
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnknownHostException: Unknown host: 
rmi://192.168.101.137/BankServer; nested exception is: 
    Java.net.UnknownHostException: rmi://192.168.101.137/BankServer
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:616)
    at 
sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at atm.ATM.main(ATM.java:52)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: rmi://192.168.101.137/BankServer
    at 
java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at...
```

Now what could be happening here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to run the VMs? What network configuration? Are you able to telnet onto the running VMs?

Comment: `getRegistry()` takes a host (name or literal address) and/or port, not a URL. The error is because it's trying to treat the URL as a hostname and it isn't a hostname. Since you have hosts with IPv4 addresses but apparently not DNS names and the default port (1099), pass it the dotted address as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove `rmi://` when you get the registry

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()` is a hostname, not an RMI URL. See the Javadoc.